# Animate a div to move left to right then back

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to animate a div to move across the web page from left to right.  I then need it to stop when it reaches all the way to the right start rotating and then while spinning move to the center of the page

I have this so far

```
@keyframes move
    {
        0%   {left: 0%;}
        50%  {left: 100%;}
        100% {left: 50%;;}
    }


    body {
        background: white;
    }

    .square {
        background: black;
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
        position: absolute;
        animation: move 5s;

    }
```

but I know very little about css animations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This maybe?

I'm uncertain if the square is supposed to keep spinning when it gets to the enter. That's a different matter without an easy CSS-only solution.

```css
@keyframes move
    {
        0%   {
            left: 0%;
          transform: rotate(0deg) ;
        }
        50%  {
          left: 100%;
          transform: rotate(0deg) ;
        }
        52% {
         transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
        70% {
          transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        100% {
          left: 50%;
          transform: rotate(360deg);}
    }



    body {
        background: white;
    }

    .square {
        background: black;
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
        position: absolute;
        animation: move 5s linear forwards;
    }
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```